# Find length of a nested array's object children

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript object. Is there a built-in or accepted best practice way to get the length of all the children , here in this case for the first object in array it should be one and for the second object two , and the total comes down to 3.

```
const testData = [
    {
        account: "A",
        children: [
            {
                account: "Test",
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    }, {
        account: "B",
        children: [
            {
                account: "Test1",
                children: [],
            },
            {
                account: "Test2",
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },

]
```

Comment: Does this need to be recursive? Ie, if the top object has children of children do you need to total them up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive solution, should you need it

```js
const testData = [
    {
        account: "A",
        children: [
            {
                account: "Test",
                children: [{account:"Test-Grandchild", children:[{account:"Test-Great-Grandchild", children:[]}]}],
            },
        ],
    }, {
        account: "B",
        children: [
            {
                account: "Test1",
                children: [],
            },
            {
                account: "Test2",
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },

]

const countChildren = obj => obj.children.length + obj.children.reduce((acc,c) => acc + countChildren(c), 0 );
const result = testData.reduce ( (acc,c) => acc + countChildren(c),0)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const nOfTestDataChildren = [
    {
        account: "A",
        children: [
            {
                account: "Test",
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    }, {
        account: "B",
        children: [
            {
                account: "Test1",
                children: [],
            },
            {
                account: "Test2",
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },
].reduce( (acc, val) => acc + val.children.length, 0);

console.log(nOfTestDataChildren);
```

Comment: This won't work deeper in the object though –– I think a recursive solution is needed

Answer (score 2):

I think `Kooilnic`'s answer perfect for the situation since we are reducing the array into a single number value and it should be accepted as the actual answer. But I want to propose another solution using [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const testData = [
    {
        account: "A",
        children: [
            {
                account: "Test",
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    }, {
        account: "B",
        children: [
            {
                account: "Test1",
                children: [],
            },
            {
                account: "Test2",
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },

]
let numberOfChildren = 0
testData.forEach(datum => numberOfChildren += datum.children.length)
console.log({ numberOfChildren })
```